# Spring security oauth2 login and resource server in same application

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have an application where users/applications can authenticate either with an OpenID provider or with a JWT token.
Here is my spring security configuration class.

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService()).and()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }

private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
    return oidcUserRequest -> {
        OidcUserService oidcUserService = new OidcUserService();
        OidcUser oidcUser = oidcUserService.loadUser(oidcUserRequest);
        return oidcUser;
    };
}
```

}

It's working as expected but I would like to disable session creation for the JWT authorization part. Do I need to split this into multiple configurations? I understand that if we have multiple configuration classes we need to differentiate based on URL pattern which I can't do in my case as a user authenticated via OpenId or via JWT still should be able to access the same URLs.

Here is the complete sample code in [Github](https://github.com/kiranreddykasa/oauth2client-resource-server).

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, you dont "authenticate using a jwt-token". When you have authenticated yourself you are presented with a JWT token that you can use to identify yourself with. Is like saying "im taking my drivers licence by showing my drivers licence". You take your drivers test, and get presented a licence that you can then use to show when you need to buy a car etc.

Comment: I meant authorize with JWT token.

Comment: Could you explain what the flow looks like when a user arrives at your application? I ask because I typically see OAuth2 login used to secure a UI (that may return HTML) and OAuth2 resource server to secure an API (that may return JSON). What does an endpoint look like that can be accessed by either one?

Comment: Generally, we split the applications like as you mentioned but in my case UI application and API is embedded in the same application for now. External clients can call "/api**" with JWT token. The embedded Angular app as well needs to invoke the same API so we added the Oauth2 login flow for the embedded UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by splitting the configuration into two classes. One for OAuth login and the other for the resource server. Configured
`http.requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))`
on the resource server Configuration class and made it's Order as 1 and Open Id configuration order as 2. In Resource server configuration I have disabled session creation.

In this way, if any external clients are calling with a JWT token with header 'Authorization' then it will be handled by Resource server configuration or else it will be handled by the second/OAuth configuration.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how does the UI part get the token to later use it with the resource server?