# How to configure Spring Boot to authenticate Web-app users and REST clients using AWS Cognito (OAuth2/OIDC)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, oauth, amazon-cognito

I need to configure a Spring Boot server to authenticate web-users and REST clients using AWS Cognito user-pool:

1. Interactive/Web users that are using the ReachJS frontend should be redirected to Cognito for authentication, and are redirected back once the user's credentials are verified.
2. Other machines using the server's REST API directly should get a token from Cognito and send it to my server as the `Authorization: Bearer ...` header.

Questions are:

1. How to configure spring to authenticate using Cognito
2. How do you make spring supporting these two distinct types of authentication simultaneously

Answer (score 4):

## Overview

Lets start with terminology:

1. IDP (Identity Provider) is a 3rd party providing user management and authentication service, AWS Cognito in my case.
2. Authentication of interactive/web users by redirecting them to the IDP is referred to in OAuth2/OIDC as the "Authorization Code Grant Flow".
3. Client sending JWT tokent to a REST API is known as the "Client Credentials Flow".

Spring's `spring-security-oauth2-client` module is responsible for the "Authorization Code Grant Flow" and the `spring-security-oauth2-resource-server` module is responsible for the "Client Credentials Flow".

In order to use both flows/methods simultaneously, we need to tell spring how do determine what authentication method to use with an incoming HTTP request.
As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64752665/2692895, this can be done by looking for the `Authorization: bearer ...` header:

1. If the request includes the `Authorization` header, assume its a REST client and use the "Client Credentials Flow".
2. Else, its an interactive user, redirect to Cognito if not already authenticated.

## Dependencies

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.6.6 (Spring 5.6.2).

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

## External Configuration - `application.yaml`

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      # Interactive/web users authentication
      client:
        registration:
          cognito:
            clientId: ${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}
            clientSecret: ${COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET}
            scope: openid
            clientName: ${CLIENT_APP_NAME}
        provider:
          cognito:
            issuerUri: https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${COGNITO_POOL_ID}
            user-name-attribute: email

      # REST API authentication
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/${COGNITO_POOL_ID}
```

## Spring Security Configuration

Interactive/web users authentication:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    // Needed for method access control via the @Secured annotation
    prePostEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true
)
@Profile({"cognito"})
@Order(2)
public class CognitoSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            // TODO disable CSRF because when enabled controllers aren't initialized
            //  and if they are, POST are getting 403
            .csrf().disable()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .oauth2Client()

            .and()
            .logout()

            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .redirectionEndpoint().baseUri("/login/oauth2/code/cognito")
            .and()
        ;
    }
}
```

REST clients authentication:

```java
/**
 * Allow users to use a token (id-token, jwt) instead of the interactive login.
 * The token is specified as the "Authorization: Bearer ..." header.
 * </p>
 * To get a token, the cognito client-app needs to support USER_PASSWORD_AUTH then use the following command:
 * <pre>
 *     aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --output json \
 *         --region $region --client-id $clientid --auth-parameters "USERNAME=$username,PASSWORD=$password" \
 *         | jq .AuthenticationResult.IdToken
 * </pre>
 */
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@Profile({"cognito"})
@Order(1)
public class CognitoTokenBasedSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
        ;
    }

}
```

## Cognito Configuration Notes

- In AWS Cognito, you need to create a user-pool and two client-applications, a "Public client" for the interactive/web users and a "Confidential client" for the token based REST clients.
- In the "Public client", make sure to define the "allowed callback URL" for all your environments (localhost, production etc), they all should be similar to http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/cognito (with the correct host-name and port of course).

Answer (score 1):

Another aspect of configuring Rest client authentication is to allow processing of groups defined in AWS in order to be able to recognize them in the application rest apis annotated with @Secured("ROLE_**")

So to support that we should make a little change in CognitoTokenBasedSecurityConfiguration

```java
@Slf4j
@Order(1)
@Profile("cognito")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CognitoTokenBasedSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .requestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"))
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CognitoJwtAuthenticationConverter())
        ;
    }
}
```

And implement CognitoJwtAuthenticationConverter which would be responsible on extracting the groups are assigned to JWT object accessing the app and creation of JwtAuthenticationToken with those groups

```java
public class CognitoJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt source)
    {
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(
            source,
            Stream.concat(
                new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter().convert(source).stream(),
                extractResourceRoles(source).stream()
                )
                .collect(toSet())
        );
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractResourceRoles(Jwt jwt)
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(jwt.getClaims().get("cognito:groups"))
            .map(groups -> (List<String>) groups)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(group -> group.startsWith("ROLE_"))
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .toList();
    }
}
```

Also it is advised to remember that annotation EnableWebSecurity should be put on the class implementing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with the lowest order , and on the other classes implementing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter should be annotated with EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.